# resolve ip address to domain name/hostname in browser

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat-enterprise-linux, redhat-classic

I configured DNS server and able to resolve ip to doamin and domain to ip in terminal. If am trying to resolve domain name over browser that is also working but i want to open my website via ip but instead ip " domain name " should come in link .

how it could be done through DNS ??

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying you want to type your site's IP address into your browser's address bar and have it switch to showing your site's domain name?

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done through DNS: When you type `http://1.2.3.4` in the browser, the browser uses the IP address directly, DNS is not involved.

However, you can lookup DNS information by IP address with the right tools from the command line, **if** this information has been entered in the DNS server. The keyword is "reverse DNS lookup", google. There are also webpages that offer this service, but none of them can replace your link automatically.